# How can I update my usercontrol when I set a value in a dependency object?

Tags: c#, wpf

This is the part where is not working. My dependency property has a default value which is Entradas.Entero, and that value must be run this line:

```
Grid.SetColumnSpan(button0, 3);
```

And it should refresh it in my user control design, however there's no changes in it.

```
public partial class TableroUserControl : UserControl
{
    public enum Entradas
    {
        Entero, Decimal
    }

    public Entradas Entrada
    {
        get { return (Entradas)GetValue(EntradaProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EntradaProperty, value); }
    }

    static void textChangedCallBack(DependencyObject property, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Button button0 = ((TableroUserControl)property).button0;

        switch ((Entradas)args.NewValue)
        {
            case Entradas.Entero:
                Grid.SetColumnSpan(button0, 3);
                break;
            case Entradas.Decimal:
                Grid.SetColumnSpan(button0, 2);
                break;
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EntradaProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Entrada", typeof(Entradas), typeof(TableroUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(Entradas.Entero, new PropertyChangedCallback(textChangedCallBack)));

    public TableroUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also consider doing this with a value converter.   You should be able to bind the Grid.ColumnSpan attached property of button0  to   the   Entrada property of your user control.  Then use a value converter to convert it to an integer. This way you don't have to deal with callbacks and state/timing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your dependency property is initialized to Entero. So unless the value is changed to Decimal and then again changed back to Entero you wont hit the property changed callback code.
Make sure that the colspan setter code is hit.